# Is it OK to use jQuery in Angular directives to perform animations?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I wrote a simple directive for my `sidebar` to perform some basic animations, such as sliding in and also modifying the width and margin of the `content` class.

My question is that is it OK to use jQuery animations in this way:

```
//sidebar directive, slides in and out on click
projectDirectives.directive('sideBar', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        var $sidebar = element.find('#navbar');
        var $content = $('.content');
        element.find('#nav_icon').on('click', function(event){
          if(!scope.navbar){
            scope.navbar = true;
            scope.margin = parseInt($sidebar.css('marginLeft'));
            scope.contentWidth = parseInt($content.css('width'));
            $content.animate({'width':scope.contentWidth - Math.abs(scope.margin) + 'px',
                'marginLeft':Math.abs(scope.margin)
            });
            $sidebar.animate({'marginLeft':0});
          } else {
            scope.navbar = false;
            $content.animate({'width':scope.contentWidth + 'px',
                'marginLeft': 0
            });
            $sidebar.animate({'marginLeft':scope.margin+'px'});
          }
        })
      },
      controller: ['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.margin = null;
        $scope.navbar = false;
        $scope.contentWidth = null;
      }]
    };
}
```

It works, but I know that there are very specific and common conventions as to how an Angular project is structured

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Mixing jQuery with AngularJs is a bad practice since you can do it with AngularJs.

[A good answer for your question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background/15012542#15012542)

*Hope this helps!*

Comment: That makes sense, the "Angular" way always confuses me, thanks.

Comment: @ZachPerkitny Glad I could help!